# How do I prevent the icons inside my spinner from spinning?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have created a spinner with a pause icon inside. It's working ok at the moment, but the pause icon seems to be spinning along with the rest of the spinner. I don't want it to spin. But I want the spinner with the orange circle to keep spinning. How do I that?

Here is my code on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TeO86IBz4VL9SXS11SPu?p=preview)

```
    <span class="spinner fa-spin">
        <i class="fa fa-pause fa-inverse fa-lg">  </i>
    </span>


    <style>
      .spinner {
          height: 40px;
          width: 40px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          margin: -20px -20px 0 0;
          border: 3px solid #F2B049;
          border-top: 3px solid #E6FFFC;
          border-left: 3px solid #E6FFFC;
          background-color: #1FBBA6;
          border-radius: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 40px;
      }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TeO86IBz4VL9SXS11SPu?p=preview) and relevant code. If you have suggestions on how to improve this, please let me know. :D

```
Correct: 
    <Br/>
    <div class="spinner-wrapper relative">
      <span class="spinner fa-spin inline-block" ></span>
      <div class="put-on-top">
        <i class="fa fa-pause fa-inverse fa-lg"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <style>
      .relative {
        position: relative;
      }
      .put-on-top {

        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        line-height: 45px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .spinner-wrapper {

        display: inline-block;
      }
      .inline-block {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .spinner {
          height: 40px;
          width: 40px;
          border: 3px solid #F2B049;
          border-top: 3px solid #E6FFFC;
          border-left: 3px solid #E6FFFC;
          background-color: #1FBBA6;
          border-radius: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 40px;
      }
```